# Replace the same set of variable with a single variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to replace all the `%variable1%, %variable2%, %variable3%, %variable4%` with a single set of variable without calling the same repeatedly as the argument size is fixed on my program, Is there any process through which it can be done with only SQL query?

```
SELECT 
    b.cons_no, b.NAME , b.cat_cd, b.bill_no, b.bill_date, 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         a.cons_cd cons_no, a.cons_name NAME, a.category_cd cat_cd,
         a.bill_no bill_no, TO_CHAR (a.proc_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
         bill_date 
     FROM 
         mstcons_bill_print a, mstcons b
     WHERE 
         b.cons_cd = a.cons_cd
         AND due_date < TRUNC (SYSDATE)
         AND a.bill_no IN (
                  SELECT TO_CHAR (MAX (bill_no))
                  FROM mstcons_bill_print
                  WHERE cons_cd IN (
                              SELECT cons_cd
                              FROM mstcons x, mstdtc z
                              WHERE x.dtc_cd = z.dtc_cd
                                AND x.dtc_cd LIKE '%variable1%'
                                AND x.category_cd LIKE '%variable2%'
                                AND x.route LIKE '%variable3%'
                                AND z.feeder_cd LIKE '%variable4%')
                  GROUP BY cons_cd
                  MINUS
                  SELECT TO_CHAR (MAX (bill_no))
                  FROM trnpaymnt_dtls
                  WHERE cons_cd IN (
                              SELECT cons_cd
                              FROM mstcons x, mstdtc z
                              WHERE x.dtc_cd = z.dtc_cd
                                AND x.dtc_cd LIKE '%variable1%'
                                AND x.category_cd LIKE '%variable2%'
                                AND x.route LIKE '%variable3%'
                                AND z.feeder_cd LIKE '%variable4%')
                  GROUP BY cons_cd)) b,
       (SELECT   c.bill_no bill_no,
                 SUM (c.achd_cd) bill_net,
                 SUM (c.achd_cd) bill_paid
            FROM trncons_achd c
           WHERE c.achd_cd IN ('CURDMD', 'ARRE', 'CURINT', 'INTA')
            AND c.bill_no IN (
                    SELECT   TO_CHAR (MAX (bill_no))
                        FROM mstcons_bill_print
                       WHERE cons_cd IN (
                                SELECT cons_cd
                                  FROM mstcons x, mstdtc z
                                 WHERE x.dtc_cd = z.dtc_cd
                                   AND x.dtc_cd LIKE '%variable1%'
                                 AND x.category_cd LIKE '%variable2%'
                                 AND x.route LIKE '%variable3%'
                                 AND z.feeder_cd LIKE '%variable4%')
                    GROUP BY cons_cd
                    MINUS
                    SELECT   TO_CHAR (MAX (bill_no))
                        FROM trnpaymnt_dtls
                       WHERE cons_cd IN (
                                SELECT cons_cd
                                  FROM mstcons x, mstdtc z
                                 WHERE x.dtc_cd = z.dtc_cd
                                   AND x.dtc_cd LIKE '%variable1%'
                                 AND x.category_cd LIKE '%variable2%'
                                 AND x.route LIKE '%variable3%'
                                 AND z.feeder_cd LIKE '%variable4%')
                    GROUP BY cons_cd)
        GROUP BY c.bill_no) a
    WHERE a.bill_no = b.bill_no AND a.bill_net - a.bill_paid > 300;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. But you can definitely improve readability of your script by extracting the sub-queries into CTEs.

Comment: Opus haven't provided other details Databae is Oracle 9i. And I want to replave the same with a single variable is that possible?

Comment: What I want is that I don't want to repeateadly provide this variable on my query. As I have fixed the 4 variables from the front end and I cannot extent as all the variables are same. So is there any provision. Kindly guide/help. Thanks